# How to change collection type in inheritance class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a base class that defines a collection `List<Person>`. Now, one specific class extending the base class should change the *collection type*.

Is that possible?

```
public class Request {
    private List<Person> persons;

    //getter, setter
}


public class SubRequest1 extends Request {
}

public class SubRequest2 extends Request {
}

//only this class should define a different list type
public class SubRequest3 {
    private List<SubRequest3.Person> persons;

    //compiler error. this is invalid code!
    @Override
    public List<SubRequest3.Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPersons(List<SubRequest3.person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    static class SubRequest3.Person extends Person {

    }
}
```

Comment: Create an Interface that is implemented by Person and SubRequest3.Person. Then have your getPersons() and setPersons use that interface.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can't override fields, you can only hide them.

The correct way to handle this situation is to declare `Person` as a common interface. The subclasses of `Request` can use different implementations of `Person`, but the calling code probably shouldn't care about the concrete type.

```
interface Person
{
    //...
}

interface Request<T extends Person>
{
    void setPeople(List<T> person);
    List<T> getPeople();
}

abstract class DefaultRequest implements Request<Person>
{
    private List<Person> persons;

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) { /* ... */ }
    public List<Person> getPeople()  { /* ... */ }
}

class SubRequest1 extends DefaultRequest 
{
    //...
}

class SubRequest2 extends DefaultRequest 
{
    //...
}

class SubRequest3 implements Request<SpecialPerson>
{
    private List<SpecialPerson> persons;

    public void setPeople(List<SpecialPerson> people) { /* ... */ }
    public List<SpecialPerson> getPeople()  { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: So I'd have to create a **generic** interface that's implemented by each Subrequest? Could I also implement that interface inside `Request` directly, so I don't have to implement it explicit in each SubRequest (beside SubRequest3)?

Comment: @membersound Updated my answer with an example. If you want to share the behaviour across multiple requests then you need an interface and an abstract class. If there's limited shared behaviour (just the get and set, and shared list field) then I'd be very tempted to just duplicate it in the 2 concrete classes. I always avoid try to avoid inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, I see. It's not possible without introducing an `abstract` class?

Comment: @membersound without introducing an abstract class **or** duplicating a little bit of code, yep.

Comment: Ok fine. Now only question is: favor inheritance or composition here? `DefaultRequest<T extends Person>` vs `DefaultRequest implements Request<Person>`. What would be the advantage of using an interface, if anyways any SubRequests are supposed to have the persons Collection?

Answer (score 1):

The subclass cannot override a method and change the return type. There are two possible ways to allow the subclass send a different type of element in the person list.

Both of these suppose that `SpecialPerson` is a subclass of `Person`:

**1 - Make the `Request` class generic:**

```
public class Request<P extends Person> {
    private List<P> persons;

    public List<P> getPersons() {
       //...
    }
}
```

With that, `SubRequest3` will be declared as:

```
public class SubRequest3 extends Request<SubRequest3.Person> {
    private List<SubRequest3.Person> persons;
}
```

All other `SubRequest` classes will declare `extends Request<Person>`

**2 - Keep everything at API level as i**s, but add instances of `SubRequest3.Person` to a list, rather than trying to return some `List<SubRequest3.Person>`. This takes advantage of the `Person/SubRequest3.Person` inheritance, while avoiding the issue of invariance associated with `List<Person>`/`List<SubRequest3.Person>`

```
private List<SubRequest3.Person> persons;

public void setPersons(List<Person> people) { 
    //cast element by element
    this.persons.clear(); //or whatever means of resetting
    people.stream().forEach(p -> persons.add((SubRequest3.Person) p));
}
public List<SubRequest3.Person> getPersons()  { 
    //Can also use a loop and add manually to a `List<Person>` object
    return this.persons.stream().map(p -> (Person) p).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare your class to accept a generic type `T` which `extends Person`:

```
public class Request<T extends Person> {
    private final List<T> people = new ArrayList<>(); // or any other implementation

    public void setPeople(List<? extends T> people){
        this.people.clear();
        this.people.addAll(people);
    }

    public List<T> getPeople(){
        return people;
    }
}
```

And then let your subclasses define what type should be used. E.g:

```
public class SubRequest3 extends Request<SubRequest3.Person>{ /* ... */ }
```

You may have seen that the `people` list is final, which means it will never be overriden. This attempt is a lot more safer than just accepting any `List` implementation, because you can ensure that the implementation does what you actually want. E.g. no harmful List can be passed via `setPeople`.

Like in the [answer from @Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359569/5515060) you might aswell want to declare a Default implementation which declares `T` to just be `Person` and then let `SubRequest1` and `SubRequest2` extend that default class.